# Google Cloud Storage URL Signing

Tags: python, elixir, google-cloud-storage

I have a signer that works great for uploading and downloading from GCS.  Great!  The signer looks like this:

```
def sign_url(client, bucket, key, opts \\ []) do
  verb = opts[:verb] || "GET"
  md5_digest = opts[:md5_digest] || ""
  content_type = opts[:content_type] || ""
  expires = opts[:expires] || Utils.years(10)
  resource = "/#{bucket}/#{key}"

  signature =
    [verb, md5_digest, content_type, expires, resource]
    |> Enum.join("\n")
    |> generate_signature(client)

  url = "#{@base_url}#{resource}"

  qs =
    %{
      "GoogleAccessId" => client.client_email,
      "Expires" => expires,
      "Signature" => signature
    }
    |> URI.encode_query()

  Enum.join([url, "?", qs])
end

defp generate_signature(string, client) do
  private_key = get_private_key(client)

  string
  |> :public_key.sign(:sha256, private_key)
  |> Base.encode64()
end

defp get_private_key(client) do
  client.private_key
  |> :public_key.pem_decode()
  |> Kernel.hd()
  |> :public_key.pem_entry_decode()
end
```

The issue I have is if I want to add an `x-goog` header, such as `x-goog-copy-source`.  Doing that, I get the error:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
```

Now, I know signed URL's support the custom headers, but I'm not sure how to update the signing to support it.  I can find no resources online, including the Google docs, that describe this.

Has anyone else had experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code a bit to add headers. They're expected after expires in the string to sign.

I don't know Elixir well enough, but hopefully this points you in the right direction. It's based off the Ruby Storage implementation (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-storage/lib/google/cloud/storage/file/signer_v2.rb#L62)

Edit: Documentation on this construction can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls-v2).

```
def sign_url(client, bucket, key, opts \\ []) do
  verb = opts[:verb] || "GET"
  md5_digest = opts[:md5_digest] || ""
  content_type = opts[:content_type] || ""
  expires = opts[:expires] || Utils.years(10)
  resource = "/#{bucket}/#{key}"
  headers = 
    Enum.map(opts[:headers], fn ({key, value}) -> "#{key}:#{value}" end)
           |> Enum.join("\n")

  signature =
    [verb, md5_digest, content_type, expires, headers, resource]
    |> Enum.join("\n")
    |> generate_signature(client)

  url = "#{@base_url}#{resource}"

  qs =
    %{
      "GoogleAccessId" => client.client_email,
      "Expires" => expires,
      "Signature" => signature
    }
    |> URI.encode_query()

  Enum.join([url, "?", qs])
end

defp generate_signature(string, client) do
  private_key = get_private_key(client)

  string
  |> :public_key.sign(:sha256, private_key)
  |> Base.encode64()
end

defp get_private_key(client) do
  client.private_key
  |> :public_key.pem_decode()
  |> Kernel.hd()
  |> :public_key.pem_entry_decode()
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what the problem was.  I had actually figured it out about an hour after posting, but upvoting this as it's the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know! Cheers